# Помогите разобраться с перенаправлением ошибок bash linux

Tags: linux, bash

Если я правильно понял, то >>2 в конце команды find перенаправляет ошибку чтения в файл, вместо того, чтобы выводить ее в консоль

```
     for dir in $(find $1 -maxdepth $2 -mindepth $2 -type d 2>>/tmp/err.txt);
```

После всех манипуляций пишется вот что:

```
IFS=$(printf '\n\t')

for error in $(cat /tmp/err.txt);
do
echo $(basename $0): ${error} >&2
done
```

С этими строчками требуется помощь в объяснении

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2>>/tmp/err.txt` - это перенаправление stderr(поток ошибок) команды find в файл /tmp/err.txt

---

`IFS=$(printf '\n\t')` - устанавливается разделитель строк на перенос строки`\n` или знак табуляции`\t`
Делается это для того, что бы в цикле `for` пробел не считался разделителем.
Аналог команды без вызова сторонних программ: `IFS=$'\n\t'`

```
#Цикл по ошибкам полученным в ходе выполнения find
for error in $(cat /tmp/err.txt);
do
#Выводится наименование скрипта без пути и суффикса 
#двоеточие, после чего идет строка из файла с перенаправленными ошибками
    echo $(basename $0): ${error} >&2
done
```